# some integral of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a problem :

Let $C$ be a curve defined by $C := \{\ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 |\ x^4 + y^4 = 1\}$,
and let $k$ be its curvature.
Compute the integral  $\int_C k$

This is an problem in a exam

What is the definition of the integral?
And how can I evaluate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Global Gauss-Bonnet Theorem :

$$ \int_{C = \partial R} k_g +\int\int_R K =2\pi \chi (R)\ ( \ast)$$

Since $R$ is a plane so $\chi(R)=1$ and Gauss curvature $K$ is $0$.

Also, geodesic curvature $k_g$ is equal to curvature $k$ because of plane.

Hence $2\pi$.

( Given curve is just a simple closed curve with no singularity so that there exists no external angle term in $\ast$ )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, what values the characteristic function has as the image?

Comment: It is Euler characteristic so that it has integers as image.

Comment: One more queation~ I know tha because R is a plane, geodesic curvature and curvature have the same absolute value. But how are they exactly equal?

Comment: Consider a curve $c $ parametrized by arc-length on a surface $S $. Its covariant derivative $\frac{D }{dt}  c(t) $ is a projection of $c ' (t)  $ into $T_{ c(t) }S $. Note that a geodesic curvature is $N\times c'(t)\cdot \frac{D }{dt}  c(t)=k_g$. That is two curvatures have same sign.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5):

For any curve in $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $s \mapsto \vec{x}(s)$ be a parametrization of the curve by its arc length. In terms of this parametrization, the tangent vector $\vec{t}(s)$, normal vector $\vec{n}(s)$ and curvature $\kappa(s)$ are "defined" by the relations:

$$\frac{d}{ds} \vec{x}(s) = \vec{t}(s) 
\quad\quad\text{ and }\quad\quad
\frac{d}{ds} \vec{t}(s) = \kappa(s) \vec{n}(s),\;\;|\vec{n}(s)| = 1
$$
Please note that in this definition, there is an ambiguity which direction the normal vectors $\vec{n}(s)$ point to. The common convention is pick the directions such that $\vec{n}(s)$ 
is as smooth as possible. If the curve doesn't have any point of inflection, i.e the curvature $\kappa(s)$ never vanishes, there are essentially only two "set" of choices
of directions of $\vec{n}(s)$ over the whole curve.

One consequence of above definition is

$$|\kappa(s)| = \left|\frac{d}{ds}\vec{t}(s)\right|\tag{*1}$$

For any curve on the plane, let $\theta(s)$ be the angle between $\vec{t}(s)$ and $x$-axis. 
Same as $\vec{n}(s)$, there is an ambiguity of what value of $\theta(s)$ should be. This is because $\theta(s)$ is well defined only up to a multiple of $2\pi$. The convention is
again choose $\theta(s)$ to be as smooth as possible over the whole curve.
In terms of $\theta(s)$, we have:

$$\vec{t}(s) = (\cos \theta(s), \sin \theta(s))\tag{*2}$$

Substitute $(*2)$ into $(*1)$, one find

$$|\kappa(s)| = \left|\frac{d\theta(s)}{ds}\right|$$

For the curve $x^4 + y^4 = 1$, if you walk around it in ccw direction, you will find
$\frac{d\theta(s)}{ds} > 0$ and the corresponding $\theta(s)$ increases for $2\pi$ after you return to original spot$\color{blue}{^{[1]}}$. This means up to a sign, the integral you want to evaluate is

$$\int \kappa(s)ds = \int \frac{d\theta(s)}{ds} ds = \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta = 2\pi$$

**Notes**

$\color{blue}{[1]}$ 
Let $L$ be the length of the curve, we wish to justify the assertion $\theta(L) - \theta(0) = 2\pi$ here.

Let $( r(s), \varphi(s) )$ be the polar coordinate of the curve. i.e.
$$s\quad\mapsto\quad\vec{x}(s) = ( r(s)\cos\varphi(s), r(s)\sin\varphi(s) )$$
WOLOG, we will also assume $s$ is chosen such that $\varphi(s) = 0$.
One observation is that when $\theta(s)$ are chosen appropriately, then $0 < \theta(s) - \varphi(s) < \pi$ over the whole curve. Since $\varphi(L) = 2\pi$, we get

$$| \theta(L) - \theta(0) - 2\pi | = |(\theta(L) - \varphi(L)) - (\theta(0) - \varphi(0))| < 2\pi\tag{*3}$$
Since $s = L$ and $s = 0$ represent the same point on the curve, $\theta(L) = \theta(0)$
up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$. $(*3)$ then implies the difference is exactly $2\pi$.

Comment: It's sooo long, and detailed, but nice! Thanks a lot:)